# JSON external file vs defined in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

What are some arguments as to when to use JSON external file such as with jQuery's

```
$.getJSON('external.json',function(data){});
```

(ajax retrieving) versus defining it in javascript with

```
var myJson = { "someVar": { "1": ["test1","test2"], "2": ["test3","test4"]} }
```

What is the "proper" way of doing it? Does it depend on JSON length or are there any other factors that can tell you what approach to use?

The way I see it: choose between loading another file which is supposed to be slow as you are loading data via ajax call or adding plenty of lines into already packed javascript file which is not a good thing either. Surely there must be some distinction as to where you should use one or another ... ?

I am not interested only in speed difference (getting file from ajax is of course slower) but also in other aspects such as what is generally used when and what should be used in some case ...

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

This is an Ajax request which will take more time than having a simple JSON object into the file.
I would prefer the second one IF it's possible. Also if you attend to have good performances the first one is longer.

*time( Loading+parsing 2 files ) >> time( Read a Javascript object )*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that first one is ajax call only... But still: having 150 lines of json defined in javascript is not a really nice and clear solution either, or is it?

Comment: It's not a problem. And you can write it on one single line. What I would do: use coffeescript and use a glue script that will append the content of one file to the other.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is known at page creation time you're probably best to use an object literal like:

```
var myJson = {...}
```

However, as Kursion mentions,

```
$.getJSON(...)
```

is a shorthand method for retrieving json data asynchronously via ajax. You'd use it if you want to retrieve data from the server that wasn't known at the time of page load...

For example, if a user enters a search term in an input control, you might want to retrieve JSON in response to that without performing a whole page update. You couldn't simply define a javascript object up-front because you wouldn't know what the search term was in advance.